# Migrate listitem workflow?

Tags: workflow, migration, metadata

We have an out-of-the-box approval workflow. Now we need to migrate items with workflow information (approval status, who approved, what comments were made) to another site.

What needs to be done? For example, there is the workflow history list where approval workflow history is stored. Do we need to map unique Ids between these lists?

Is this doable with reasonable effort using CSOM or web services? If not could we do this using server-side object model? If not are there 3rd party migrator applications that could do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are third party tools that can migrate workflows but I have never had 100% success.  Look at AVePoint and MetaLogix, they have trial versions of their tools you can look at.

list workflows - unless built in Visual studio are not portable.  If it's OOTB or SharePoint Designer, your workflow will be associated directly with a list and tied to specific list ID"s.

You can migrate the list data with no issue.

workflow history list is good for live workflows but is not a good location to keep long term results.  If you need to capture this data I would have the workflow writing to a dedicated list.

Since you are using OOTB workflows - the Lists should be identicle on both sites.  You can copy the data from one list to the other and just map the columns for the workflow data.  If you have any in-process items, let them finish or start them new on the new list.  Dont try to move workflow history, you wont be able to map that back to any items, all the ID's and associations will be different. If you have version history you want to keep and keep the Created by / Modified Stamps I would use PowerShell to move the data.